# How do you explain an English speaker what Foute Muziek ("Wrong Music") is?

Tags: translation

Foute Muziek (literally translated: "Wrong Music") is a music genre that plays on radios in the Netherlands. Internationally well-known songs that made it to the top-10 ([source](https://qmusic.nl/hitlijsten/top-500-van-het-foute-uur-2018)) include

- Spice Girls - Wannabe
- Abba - Dancing Queen
- Backstreet Boys - I Want it That Way

It's hard to explain what Foute Muziek is and if I would, I would answer my own question. So that's exactly what I will do (see my answer).

1. Is there a direct English translation of "Foute Muziek" that captures its meaning?
2. If not, how would you explain it to English speakers?

Comment: I was going to say "bubblegum music" based on the songs listed, but apparently that is a specific reference to a similar phenomenon in the late 1960's-1970's. This new stuff has the same general characteristics (made for easy and catchy sing-a-long, popular appeal, critics hate it). I personally call it bubblegum.

Comment: Corny/commercial/pop/catchy/teen-pop music

Answer (score 0):

I'd say foute music is music that you listen to as a "guilty pleasure".

The Dutch Google inline result when searching for `wat is foute muziek` translates to:

Generally, foute muziek is music that for some reason shouldn't be regarded as good music but actually is. However, the term can have a different meaning for everyone. So the meaning of foute muziek can't be defined.

I'd like to add that Foute Muziek is a kind of "cult". Critics of the genre might turn the definition around to: "foute muziek is music that's regarded as good music but actually isn't". Their point is very well illustrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ). Now you know what foute muziek is.

Comment: Although I utterly detest James Blunt and all he stands for, I have "Stay the Night" on my phone.

Comment: Music you never outgrew (but should have)?